# retriving blob object from data DB2.

Tags: java, blob

There is a case where last name has 'Null' ex: name = 'Sachin Null'First name = 'Sachin' Lastname= 'Null'. when we store into the database string null is in the last name. and we store it as a blob object. while retreving i am getting an empty string "" as last name.

Is the value string 'Null' is consider as a "" while retreving the blob object?